# Django debug toolbar ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware debug_toolbar.middleware: "No module named toolbar.loader"

Tags: django, debugging

I installed and configured debug_toolbar as the instruction say.[See Here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar), i could even run syncdb.But when i access the admin page i get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 283, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))

ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware debug_toolbar.middleware: "No module named toolbar.loader"
```

And I can't access any other page.Same error.
I searched for a while and couldn't find any answer.What i did wrong here?

Comment: Did you add debug toolbar middleware? `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ('debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',)`

Answer (score 4):

I will support the installation of debug_toolbar when you are inside on Virtualenv.  Just make sure that its is activated in your settings.py and then do a :

```
pip install django-debug-toolbar
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the latest version of debug toolbar?

In debug_toolbar/middleware.py the import (line 14) reads:

```
from debug_toolbar.toolbar.loader import DebugToolbar
```

See if that matches your debug_toolbar/middleware.py to start with.

It sounds like something is funky with your installation. Check that the directories are alright, and try importing the middleware from ./manage.py shell.

Then perhaps try deleting the debug_toolbar directories manually and reinstalling it with pip if all else fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using virtualenv, make sure that you have the virtualenv activated where you have installed debug_toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.2/configuration.html

1. 'debug_toolbar' -> INSTALLED_APPS
2. 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware' -> MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES (at first position)
3. define STATIC_ROOT and ./manage.py collectstatic
4. DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False
5. INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)